# How to working Android Debug Bridge

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

I trying a pregnancy app.
I want see my databases in files. 
so I trying ADB manager.

I am connect usb cable to Nexus 4 phone.
I open developer options and I open terminal

I write this

```
adb devices
```

and

```
List of devices attached 
008f5a05a390b165    device
```

I try working shell command

```
adb shell
```

and I write this

```
shell@mako:/ $ sqlite3 /data/data/com.tupbebekailesi.medyasef/databases/hamilelikrehberi.db
```

but this not working. And I get this error

```
/system/bin/sh: sqlite3: not found
```

how to see my database. Please help.
Sorry bad english.
Thank you.

Comment: you have a `production` AKA `user` build on your phone. it does not contain `sqlite3` binary. you need to `root` your phone and install the binary.

Comment: @AlexP. first thanx your answer. Yes not root my phone. Also I dont see my databases isnt ?

Comment: @AlexP. Questions are NOT duplicate. Two DIFFERENT problems have the same reason.